Как узнать тип файла в neovim
Немного тупой вопрос. Но я не пойму как узнать какой тип файла открывает neovim. Мне это нужно что его поправить. При открытии *.inc, *.frag, *.glsl и т.д он указывает или *.conf или *.pov. Что мне не нужно. Я хотел бы их настроить. Но подобная конструкция в neovim не работает (может работает в vim), а гайдов или конструкция для nvim я не нашёл:
autocmd! BufRead, BufNewFile *.frag set filetype=glsl

На этом весь вопрос.

Немного ещё поискав, я нашёл ответ.
В nvim есть функция vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd. Вот её аргументы:
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(ивент, например 'BufRead', {
    pattern=условие, например '*.txt'
    callback=функция при срабатывании, например function()
        vim.cmd(':echo "Сработало"')
    end 

Есть также и другие аргументы, но я их не знаю. На этом всё, вопрос решён.

https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#_autocmd-functions
